# Ambiguous reference between 'Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.Message' and 'Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Message

Tags: c#, azure

I am new to c# and was using some references to code. I added a few methods that use Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client while some methods use Microsoft.Azure.Devices. Now the message class ambiguous references and I need both the using statements. What can I do now?

the error message is:
"'Message' is an ambiguous reference between 'Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.Message' and 'Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Message'"

The code is:

```
using System;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;
 using Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client;
 using Microsoft.Azure.Devices;
 using Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Shared;
 using Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Provisioning.Client;
 using Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Common.Exceptions;
 using Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Provisioning.Client.Transport;
 using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
 using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

the message class is used as shown here:

```
var message = new Message(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(messageString));
```

I tried using `Client.Message`, but it does not work. I use python and am new to c# and am not sure how it works.

Can somebody explain in some detail, the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "'Message' is an ambiguous reference between 'Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.Message' and 'Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Message'"

It means that both `Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client` and `Microsoft.Azure.Devices` have a class called `Message`; you've imported both namespaces so C# is no longer certain what you mean when you say `Message`

Either remove one of the namespaces, or fully qualify Message by adding the full namespace before the name, depending on which Message class you intend to use (I can't tell either, because both of them have constructors that take a byte)

```
var cmessage = new Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.Message(...);
var dmessage = new Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Message(...);
```

If you'll be typing either of them a lot, you can use an alias for one or the other (if you stop importing one namespace because all you needed out of it is the message class) or both (if you carry on importing both namespaces):

```
using ClientMessage = Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.Message;
using DeviceMessage = Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Message;
```

Then you can say:

```
var cmessage = new ClientMessage(...);
var dmessage = new DeviceMessage(...);
```